# Using regex in R to detect a specific word anywhere in string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to write regular expressions in R to detect a word that can occur anywhere within a string, but only when it occurs as an entire word.
e.g.  in

`samplestr <- c("LT BLAHBLAH", "BLAH LT BLAH", "BLAHLT BLOO")`

I want to detect all occurances of "LT" but not cases where a word contains LT within a larger group. Desired output of grepl("regex that works",samplestr) (or similar string detection function) would be:

`TRUE TRUE FALSE`

Comment: so basically `str_detect(samplestr , "^LT| LT | LT$")`?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631361/regex-in-r-to-detect-exact-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `grep` with the regex pattern `\bLT\b`:

```r
samplestr <- c("LT BLAHBLAH", "BLAH LT BLAH", "BLAHLT BLOO")
output <- grep("\\bLT\\b", samplestr, value=TRUE)
output

[1] "LT BLAHBLAH"  "BLAH LT BLAH"
```

The pattern `\bLT\b` has *word boundaries* on either side of `LT`, which will only match `LT` when as a standalone word, or, more generally, when surrounded by non word characters.